# Winforms AutoScale inner controls of FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a custom cotrol with FlowLayoutPanel in it. the app allows user to drag and drop other custom controls to it without limitation on the number of these child controls.
What I need is some way to autscale the FlowLayoutPanel, e.g to prevent scrolling when there are too many child controls and instead resize their width and height so they would all fit in.
Also I need the ability to zoom in and out of the FlowLayoutPanel, when the max zoom in is when all the child controls are inside.
[image]

I can calculate it at runtime, but I ask here because there may be a less complicated solution that I don't know about. I googled offcourse and found only Anchor and Dock, both don't help me because it is importat that the user can change the way the child controls are located in the panel.
Please help me if anyone knows a better way, thank you.

Comment: Obviously, if you want to do that, then you have to write your own code and at that point, it is not even sure if using a FlowLayoutPanel would be of any help or if you would be better to create your own control from scratch.

Comment: It would probably be easier to do that in WPF if your inner controls could be WPF controls too. WPF does have a control for "zooming". Well, it really depends on the actual behavior. For example, does the text need to be bigger?

Comment: @Phil1970 no the text can be the same. The main issue is to avoid scrolling.

Comment: Well, I think that sometime it is better to make some compromises than trying to go around limitations of existing controls. One possibility would be to have 3 fixed sizes (small, medium and large) and use the appropriate size depending on the total available area (minus margins and padding). By having fixed size, you can easily compute how many controls fit in the width and height (assuming all controls are the same size as in your picture) and if they don't fit verify for next smaller size until you reach the minimal size in which case, the scrollbar would be displayed if still necessary.